# Parsing: ANTLR for .NET

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following text:

```
<<! notes, Test!>>
```

Grammar:

```
grammar Hello;

prog:   stat+;
stat:   DELIMETER_OPEN expr DELIMETER_CLOSE ;
expr:   NOTES value=VAR_VALUE   # delim_body ;
VAR_VALUE   : [ a-Z A-Z 0-9 ! ];
NOTES   : 'notes,'
        |   ' notes,';
DELIMETER_OPEN  :   '<<!';
DELIMETER_CLOSE :   '!>>';
```

Error:

```
line 1:12 token recognition error at: '>' 
line 1:13 token recognition error at: '>' 
line 1:10 mismatched input ' !' expecting VAR_VALUE
```

(NOTE:  Added DELIMITER defs since I forgot them earlier)

Comment: What are your rules for `DELIMITER_OPEN` and `DELIMITER_CLOSE`? Do the rules conflict with the `VAR_VALUE` rule, that contains a `!`.

Comment: @GRosenberg Sorry, I just added those now.  I am very new at parsing, so I guess I am not sure if they conflict or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grammar Hello;

prog :      stat+ EOF ;
stat :      DELIMETER_OPEN expr DELIMETER_CLOSE ;
expr :      NOTES COMMA value=VAR_VALUE   # delim_body ;

VAR_VALUE : ANBang* AlphaNum ;
NOTES :    'notes' ;
COMMA :    ','     ;
WS    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

DELIMETER_OPEN  :  '<<!';
DELIMETER_CLOSE :  '!>>';

fragment ANBang : AlphaNum | Bang ;
fragment AlphaNum : [a-zA-Z0-9] ;
fragment Bang : '!' ;
```

Ideally, the rules have to be mutually unambiguous. So, the `VAR_VALUE` rule is defined to limit the existence of a `!` from the end. This will prevent the `!` from being consumed by `VAR_VALUE` in preference to `DELIMITER_CLOSE`. Of course, that presumes the redefinition is acceptable. If not, a more involved solution will be required.

Also, as a general principle, `skip` anything that is not syntactically significant to the parsing.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know of any good places to reference various things. I am just starting with Antlr, and although this answer works, I have no idea how

Comment: While there is doc on Antlr.org, by far the best reference is [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference).  Also see [antlr/grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).